# How to call Helper Data.php file code in checkout_index_index.xml?

Tags: magento2.3.4

Hello I have installed an extension, i create system.xml with two new field,
and create Data.php in Helper folder, tha Data.php has two function to get data from core_config_data table, that two field name is `text_above_tax_number` and `text_above_tax_state`
now that two field i want to show in checkout_index_index.xml, because that display in frontend checkout page,
here is my code,

**system.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
    <tab id="bodak_checkout_custom_form" translate="label" sortOrder="0">
        <label>FMS Taxrelief</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="checkoutcustomform" translate="label"  sortOrder="100"  showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>checkout-custom-form</class>
        <label>Taxrelief</label>
        <tab>bodak_checkout_custom_form</tab>
        <resource>Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm::checkoutcustomform_config</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                <label>Module Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="tax_state" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Tax State</label>
                <source_model>Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Model\Config\TaxState</source_model>
            </field>

            <field id="text_above_tax_number" translate="label" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Text above tax number</label>
            </field>
            <field id="text_above_tax_state" translate="label" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Text above tax state</label>
            </field>

        </group>
    </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Data.php**
**`getTextAboveTaxNumber` and `getTextAboveTaxState` two function**

```
<?php
    namespace Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Helper;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
    use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
    
    class Data extends AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $context;
        
        const TEXT_ABOVE_TAX_NUMBER = 'checkoutcustomform/general/text_above_tax_number';
        const TEXT_ABOVE_TAX_STATE = 'checkoutcustomform/general/text_above_tax_state';
        
        protected $scopeConfig;
        
        public function __construct(
            Context $context, 
            //\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
        ){
            $this->context = $context;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
    
        public function isEnable()
        {
            return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkoutcustomform/general/enable', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        }
    
        public function getTextAboveTaxNumber()
        {
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkoutcustomform/general/text_above_tax_number', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        }
    
        public function getTextAboveTaxState()
        {
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkoutcustomform/general/text_above_tax_state', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        }
    
        public function getTextState()
        {
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkoutcustomform/general/tax_state', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        }
    }
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/js/view/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="checkout_buyer_name" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Buyer name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_buyer_email" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/email</item>
                                                                                        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">We will send an order confirmation to this email address</item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_email</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Buyer email</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_purchase_order_no" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_purchase_order_no</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Purchase order no.</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_goods_mark" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_goods_mark</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Goods mark</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_comment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/textarea</item>
                                                                                        <item name="cols" xsi:type="string">15</item>
                                                                                        <item name="rows" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_comment</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Comment</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: You are going to add those 2 field into shipping Address Form?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes i want that 2 field in to shipping address form in checkout_index_index.xml file